# Why can't I use 'scanf_s' for reading a character and a number at once?

Tags: c, scanf

This code crashes:

```
scanf_s("%c %d",&ch,&x);//Run error
```

But this code works:

```
scanf_s("%c",&ch);
scanf_s("%d",&x);//Run succeed
```

I want to know why the first code fragment is wrong.

'run error' means
The compiler has a warning and something is wrong when I run the program input

Comment: What is a "run error"?

Comment: Do you mean a warning issued by your compiler, or something that goes wrong once you run your program? Anyway, please show the respective message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `scanf_s` (in contrast to `scanf`), you need to provide an additional length parameter for `%c` (cf, for example, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) document from microsoft regarding `scanf_s`):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require you to specify
>   buffer sizes for some parameters. Specify the sizes for all c, C, s,
>   S, or string control set [] parameters.

So you will have to write

```
scanf_s ("%c %d", &ch, 1, &x);
```

indicating that the first `%c` shall read at most one character.

Note that `scanf_s("%c",&ch);` should issue the same warning/error as it lacks the mandatory length parameter for `%c`, too.

Command `scanf_s("%d",&x);`, in contrast, is OK as `%d` does not require (must not get provided) an additional length parameter.

Comment: MSVC is obnoxious about not using `scanf()` but does not check argument types to `scanf_s` when it is easy to do with a constant format string...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are running MSVC, which gives an error if you use `scanf` instead of `scanf_s`. I also assume you want to use the former and not the latter. To disable the error, go to Project menu -> [Project name] Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor. To the "Preprocessor Definitions" field, add the macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. Then click "Apply."

Now you should be able to use `scanf` as you would on any other compiler/IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an expansion of [the answer by Stephan Lechner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56923342/509868), consider what happens when executing `scanf_s("%c %d",&ch,&x)`.

Technically, it's undefined behavior because you didn't specify the correct parameters to `scanf_s`.

However, practically, the code will try to interpret junk values in the memory as missing parameters. That is, the code is equivalent to something like this:

```
scanf_s("%c %d", &ch, 0xf0000000, 0xdeadbeef);
```

Here `0xf0000000` represents the address of the variable `x`. The code of `scanf_s` will interpret it as buffer size (a very large buffer), but this has no effect because `%c` tells it to read just one byte. Further, `0xdeadbeef` represents junk, and the code interprets it as an address to write your integer result. Writing to random addresses is a big no-no, so it crashes.

When your code reads the `char` and the `int` separately, it never encounters writing to a random address, so everything works well, and if you ignore compiler warnings, you never know that your code is buggy.